# C# The type '…' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a method to change the string to titlecase. But I'm in trouble.

```
public string PrimeiraLetraUpper(string input)
{
   TextInfo ti = new TextInfo();
   return ti.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower());
}
```

Error:

> Error 2 The type 'System.Globalization.TextInfo' has no constructors defined

How can I solve this?

Comment: The answer is readily available in the [TextInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo(v=vs.110).aspx): "The application should use the `CultureInfo.TextInfo` property to obtain the TextInfo object for a particular `CultureInfo` object." So you need to work out which culture's casing rules you're interested in first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `TextInfo` object because it has no (public) constructor(s) ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/textinfo.cs,4d9c164eae792844,references)).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The application should use the `CultureInfo.TextInfo` property to obtain
>   the `TextInfo` object for a particular `CultureInfo` object.

So for example:

```
public string PrimeiraLetraUpper(string input, CultureInfo ci = null)
{
    if (ci == null) ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return ci.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower());
}
```